# How to get all items from a table using cloud-api auto generated API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-mobilehub

I'm working on small React Native project. I did use MobileHub and created simple Logs table (I was following that tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/react-native-access-databases.html).

```
Path to be used on API for get and remove an object should be like:
/Logs/object/:LogID/:LogKey

Path to be used on API for list objects on get method should be like:
/Logs/:LogID

JSON to be used as data on put request should be like:
{
  "LogValue": "INSERT VALUE HERE",
  "LogTime": "INSERT VALUE HERE",
  "LogID": "INSERT VALUE HERE",
  "LogKey": "INSERT VALUE HERE"
}
To test the api from the command line (after awsmobile push) use this commands
awsmobile cloud-api invoke LogsCRUD <method> <path> [init]
```

I have no issue to insert anything in database (using: API.put('LogsCRUD', '/Logs', data), or to get single items (API.get('LogsCRUD', '/Logs/1')), but **I can't find anywhere idea how to get all of the items from the table**. I checked so many things, and tried to figured it out by random names, but nothing worked.